# firebase onDiconnect with and without callback

Tags: javascript, web, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I met interesting situation.
All firebase guides and manuals say that we should use .onDisconnect method before all others operations to prevent situation when value has been already set but "onDisconnect" behaviour wasn't described (for example because of sudden internet disconnect).

For example:

```
userRef.onDisconnect().remove();
userRef.set(value);
```

But this approach didn't help me in situation when i was rapidly connecting/disconnecting my WIFI. After few disconnections I noticed that some values weren't deleted.

After that I tried to use such code:

```
userRef.onDisconnect().set(null, function(){
    userRef.set(value);
})
```

Such approach helped me to succesfully solve the problem and prevent saving unnecessary values during unstable internet connection. It is great, but I still don't understand why it works and works better then first variant.
All manuals say that it is enough to just put `onDisconnect().remove();` before other operations. May be they don't take in consideration situations with extremeley unstable connection, or I have mistaken somewhere?

Comment: If you have a so-called unclean disconnect (the network connection drops as opposed to the client being programmatically closed), it may take some time before the server detects the client is gone. The exact time depends on the socket time-outs and other variables, but typically it may take a few minutes.

Comment: After deep investigation of the my code I found places where it was possible to create record without properly setted 'onDisconnect' option.
Moreover, I understood that during developing firebase app we should choose proper approach for each of our references, I mean synchronous and asynchronous style. For example if there is some data which needs transactional type of saving you should use firebase transaction method. For all other cases you should use set and update methods, call them synchronously and rely on firebase's code itself to push changes correctly to remote database.

Comment: Good to hear that you found the solution. If you post it as an answer with relevant code snippets, it might be useful for others too.